# android telephone number

Tags: android, gsm, phone-number

I want to display my telephone number when I open the application, but I get a exception saying

> The application Telephone has ()stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I have already added `Read_Phone_State` permission in manifest file.

```
public class Telephone extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View v = new View(this);
        v.setTag("The Number is : " + getMyTenDigitsNumber());
        setContentView(v);

    }

    private String getTelephone() {
        TelephonyManager tm;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getLine1Number();

    }

    private String getMyTenDigitsNumber() {
        String s = getTelephone();
        return s.substring(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in the log?  Please post the corresponding logcat entries

Comment: I have changed getLine1Number() to getDeviceSoftwareVersion(), but the app is stilled forced to close.This is the logcat: [link](http://i106.photobucket.com/albums/m265/Mihaela15/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that `getLine1Number` is returning null so your subsequent substring operation throws a `NullPointerException` (you should be able to verify via logcat). According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) for the method, it can return null if the number is unavailable. It is possible that your provider doesn't store the phone number on the SIM so, in that case, the number may not be available to that method.

Comment: I'm testing it on my personal phone device and what logcat tells me is nullPointException, but how can I make my provider showing it?

Comment: If the provider isn't returning it, there is no way to force it. Even if it worked for your phone, there is no guarantee that it would work on phones on other providers. If you're using the phone number to uniquely identify a phone, you're better off using  getDeviceId()

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that getLine1Number() returns null, and therefore your substring operation throws an NPE. getLine1Number() returns null when the number is unavailable, like when there is no SIM card inserted, or the number is not stored on the SIM card. You can check if the number is available by going to Settings -> About phone -> Status and checking if your number is displayed in the My phone number field.

Comment: Thanks Raghav Sood, It was written that is unknown number :)